# ASHX C# for each loop on POST vars

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I have the following piece of code on C#, on an ASHX or Generic Handler file:

```
public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext contexto)
{
    string destino = contexto.Request["destino"];

    string variables = "?";

    string valor = "";

    foreach (string nombre in contexto.Request.QueryString)
    {
        if (nombre == "destino")
        {
            continue;
        } // Fin del if.
        else
        {
            if (contexto.Request.QueryString[nombre] != "")
            {
                valor = contexto.Request.QueryString[nombre];

                variables += nombre + "=" + valor + "&";
            } // Fin del if.
        } // Fin del else.
    } // Fin del foreach.

    variables = variables.Substring(0, variables.Length - 1);

    if (destino != null && destino != "")
    {
        switch (destino)
        {
            case "coordenadasPorMunicipios":    contexto.Response.Redirect("./admon/coordenadasPorMunicipios/CoordenadasPorMunicipiosControl.ashx" + variables);
                                                break;
            case "departamentos":               contexto.Response.Redirect("./admon/departamentos/DepartamentosControl.ashx" + variables);
                                                break;
            case "municipios":                  contexto.Response.Redirect("./admon/municipios/MunicipiosControl.ashx" + variables);
                                                break;
            case "negocios":                    contexto.Response.Redirect("./admon/negocios/NegociosControl.ashx" + variables);
                                                break;
            case "paises":                      contexto.Response.Redirect("./admon/paises/PaisesControl.ashx" + variables);
                                                break;
            case "sectoresIndustria":           contexto.Response.Redirect("./admon/sectoresIndustria/SectoresIndustriaControl.ashx" + variables);
                                                break;
            case "sectoresIndustriaPorNegocio": contexto.Response.Redirect("./admon/sectoresIndustriaPorNegocio/SectoresIndustriaPorNegocioControl.ashx" + variables);
                                                break;
            case "tiposNegocioPorNegocio":      contexto.Response.Redirect("./admon/tiposNegocioPorNegocio/TiposNegocioPorNegocioControl.ashx" + variables);
                                                break;
            case "tiposNegocios":               contexto.Response.Redirect("./admon/tiposNegocios/TiposNegociosControl.ashx" + variables);
                                                break;
            case "usuarios":                    contexto.Response.Redirect("./admon/usuarios/UsuariosControl.ashx" + variables);
                                                break;
        } // Fin del switch.
    } // Fin del if.
} // Fin del método ProcessRequest.
```

It works fine for GET vars, I mean, the ones that are sent via URL, but I want to do this for the POST vars.

I tryied to do a for each over he HttpContext object but I get a message that said that HttpContext class didn't have an Enumerator inmpelementation.

Any idea of how can I do this for both GET and POST vars??

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request.Form is what you are looking for, it's for POST variables

Answer (score 2):

Where `Request.QueryString` is for the GET, `Request.Form` is for the form post variables.  If you want to enumerate both at the same time, you can use `Request.Params`

Answer (score 0):

[`Request.Params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params.aspx) gives you a collection of Form, QueryString, Cookie and Server Variables, which is possibly too much, so you'll probably want to limit yourself to iterating over just `.Forms` and `.QueryString`.